# Обработка большого количества информации

Tags: excel, api

Есть текстовый документ в котором спаршено с API очень большое количество информации.
Нужно эту информацию посортировать и поукладывать в excel документ, а ненужные данные просто пропустить.
К примеру строка :

> {"previous":null,"results":[{"content_object":{"content_type":"movie","resource_url":"https://youtube.win/api/v1/movies/5/?format=json","id":5,"ru_title":"Эверест","orig_title":"Everest","imdb_id":"tt2719848","kinopoisk_id":"739642".

Из этого всего нам нужно

> "ru_title":"Эверест" "imdb_id":"tt2719848" "kinopoisk_id":"739642"

Так как данных очень много, нужно в excel распределить по столбцам:

```html
Title       IMDb          Kinopoisk

Эверест     tt2719848     739642
Титаник     tt525442      242 
....        ....          ....
```

Чем это можно сделать?

Comment: Например парсер на python написать.

Comment: Сколько такой парсер может стоить денег?

Comment: Интересная постановка задачи...  Обычно такие вопросы решаются индивидуально :)

Comment: Очень много - больше миллиона? В *Excel* поместится только 2^20 записей. *Чем это можно сделать?* - можно и с самом *Excel-VBA*

Answer (score 0):

Как написали в комментариях, это возможно разными способами:

1. Если записей меньше 1.048.576 штук, то возможно разобрать файл с помощью VBA в самом Excel и сложить данные на лист. Однако, для извлечения данных из JSON-объекта, придется использовать дополнительные приложения, вызываемые из кода VBA. Здесь же можно найти примеры подобного извлечения.
2. Если записей гораздо больше, то извлечь на лист Excel не получится. В этом случае проще написать скрипт разбора любым доступным языком, в том числе и на python, который имеет очень приятную библиотеку разбора JSON-объектов.